# Are the channels on a multi-channel DC power supply isolated from each other?

Tags: power-supply

I have a Korad 3305P, dual channel dc benchtop power supply. Are the 2 channels isolated from each other? If I ohm test the 2 negative leads, they are not connected. If I have one supply referenced to earth ground and another referenced to 300V above ground, will this blow up the power supply? The manual does not mention isolation or max isolation voltage.

Comment: Many multi-output bench PSUs have isolated outputs. Some don't. Check what the manual says.

Comment: There's usually a limit to the max allowable voltage between negative and ground; if the supply's datasheet or manual do not say, you should attempt to contact an engineer at the manufacturer to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [manual](https://familab.org/wiki/images/1/11/Korad-KA3305P.pdf), I think the two channels are isolated from each other and from GND, and also from the USB/RS-232 ports. You can verify the latter with a meter. I would expect the USB/RS-232 might be common with GND/earth.

But only when they are not in series or parallel modes with CH2 master.

You can count on the isolation being as good as the maximum output voltage (or series operation would not be reliable), but 300V is taking a chance. You might get away with it (it takes a bit of effort to make optoisolation -- if that is what is used--  bad enough to fail with 300V), but the supply is not rated for it. You could also crack it open and take a look, as in this photo from Dave Jones' excellent [eevblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/inside-the-new-korad-ka3305p-linear-psu/):

[image]

The isolation between control and output channels (the row of optos to the left) looks a *lot* better than the isolation between channels (maybe 1mm vs. several mm), but hard to tell, really.